# UK Visa before 3 months before intended date if it is an extended vacation?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I am an Indian Citizen, currently living in Canada(PR). I am traveling from Vancouver to Bombay on 17th Jan, 2020. My return flight is on March 5 from Bombay. I am stopping in UK for 5 days and my return flight from Heathrow to Vancouver is on 10th March.

As per UK visa website, you should apply 3 months before your intended travel date. In my scenario, March 5, 2020 is the date when I arrive in UK so that means I can apply latest by December 5, 2019.

I was wondering since I will leave Canada on Jan 17, 2020 can I apply to UK Visa beforehand?

How long does it take to get Biometric Appointment? Let's say even if i apply on Dec 5, 2019. Will I be able to get visa before Jan 17?

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply 3 months before your expected arrival date in the UK, and can typically expect a decision within 15 days (not guaranteed, of course). https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/vancouver-canada/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less

Note that UKVI guidance specifically states that evidence of travel bookings is not required to be submitted with an application. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk UK visit visa validity is almost always 6 months, therefore applicants are not obliged to stick to the date stated in the application and do have leeway to change their travel date after receiving their visa.